# Why aren't QObjects deleted twice, if they are class-members and childs at the same time?

Tags: qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

If a QObject is a member of a class (not created with the new-operator) and at the same time a child of the class-instance, it should be deleted twice, because all childs of the class-instance are deleted and in the desctructor of the class all class-members are deleted. Hence, the program should crash. But this doesn't happen, so Qt somehow must detect this double-relationship. But does this really happen? And if yes, how does it work?

Here is an example:

```
class MyWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWindow();
    QLabel label;
};

MyWindow::MyWindow() : label(this) {}
```

When an instance of `MyWindow` is destroyed, `label` should be deleted twice because it is a member AND a child of `MyWindow`. But this doesn't happen and it seems safe to do this. But how does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in this case, because of the order of deletion:

1. ~MyWindow() is called first, which destroys the label. The label's ~QObject() destructor removes the object from the parent's list of children.
2. After ~MyWindow(), at some point the MyWindow's ~QObject() destructor is called, which delete's the window's children. However, as the label pointer was already removed from the list of children, there is no attempt to delete the label again.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Qt documentation: `You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents.` I take that to mean that the child is responsible for the detachment as a part of its destructor. From [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Also, it may be useful to note that the order of destruction in C++ specifies that member destructors are called prior to base class destructors, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8183zf3x.aspx). So label will remove itself prior to the MyWindow needing to remove it.